# Core plot - disable scaling and scrolling in the y direction, not x

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I'm working on a graph displaying dates on the x-axis, and percent on the y-axis (1-100). I have got the graph to show kind of the way I like, but I want to disable the ability to scroll and scale the graph in y-direction, so the values 1-100 always is displayed at the same scale. However, I cannot disable user interaction completely, as I want the user to be able to scroll (and perhaps scale) in the x-direction as the number of dates gets bigger, and touch the nodes to display values.

I was able to to this in s7graphview, which I was using before, but haven't been able to get this to work with iOS 5. Also, the smooth scrolling I got from the scrollView in s7 had been fine to have in Core Plot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to set the `globalYRange` of the plot space to the same range as the `yRange`. If you need to expand the `yRange` later, remember to remove the `globalYRange` first (set it to nil).

To get more control, you can use a plot space delegate. Implement this method:

```
-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
     willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
             forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate;
```

You can use this method to modify the proposed change to the plot range.

Comment: This means that I can't scroll or scale outside the limits I set, but it is still possible to zoom in on the y-axis, which I will prevent.

Answer (score 3):

```
//for stop vertical scrolling

-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement{
        return CGPointMake(displacement.x,0);}


-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate{
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
        newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;
    }
    return newRange;}
```